# Building MySQL trigger using if statements

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am using the example MySQL database 'world' found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Here's the desc of the tables:

```
mysql> desc city; desc country; desc countrylanguage;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name        | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| CountryCode | char(3)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| District    | char(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Population  | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field          | Type                                                                                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Code           | char(3)                                                                               | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Name           | char(52)                                                                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| Continent      | enum('Asia','Europe','North America','Africa','Oceania','Antarctica','South America') | NO   |     | Asia    |       |
| Region         | char(26)                                                                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| SurfaceArea    | float(10,2)                                                                           | NO   |     | 0.00    |       |
| IndepYear      | smallint(6)                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Population     | int(11)                                                                               | NO   |     | 0       |       |
| LifeExpectancy | float(3,1)                                                                            | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GNP            | float(10,2)                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| GNPOld         | float(10,2)                                                                           | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| LocalName      | char(45)                                                                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| GovernmentForm | char(45)                                                                              | NO   |     |         |       |
| HeadOfState    | char(60)                                                                              | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Capital        | int(11)                                                                               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Code2          | char(2)                                                                               | NO   |     |         |       |
+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)

+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CountryCode | char(3)       | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| Language    | char(30)      | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| IsOfficial  | enum('T','F') | NO   |     | F       |       |
| Percentage  | float(4,1)    | NO   |     | 0.0     |       |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm trying to build a trigger where it will only delete a city from the city table if it fulfills the following conditions:

- The language is Official (countrylanguage.IsOfficial = 'T')
- Official language is not English (countrylanguage.IsOfficial <> English)
- Spoken in more than 20% of the population (countrylanguage.Percentage > 20)

This is the code I have right now-

```
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER city_45_SDD
    BEFORE DELETE ON city
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE Lang varchar(25);
        DECLARE Percent Float(4);
        DECLARE Official varchar(1);
    SELECT Language INTO Lang FROM countrylanguage;
    SELECT Percentage INTO Percent FROM countrylanguage;
    SELECT IsOfficial INTO Official FROM countrylanguage;

    IF Lang <> 'English' AND Percent > 45 AND Official = 'T'
        DELETE FROM city (ID, Name, CountryCode, District, Population);
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, so if anyone could explain to me what I did wrong, that would be amazing.

Sorry I forgot to mention the issues.

- Is the if statement formatted correctly? I've seen it in the format I wrote above and the IF (...) THEN statement.
- How would I get the DELETE FROM to use the values from the query?
- Also, is it possible to compare values from the query and from the table? How would I distinguish from say, the query's city.Name and the table's city.Name?

Comment: " explain to me what I did wrong". You forgot to mention what it is that's going wrong...

Comment: Sorry about that, I edited in the issues at the bottom of the post.

Comment: those aren't really a list of issues, it's a list of questions. Is the code not working, or doing something unexpected? In other words - 1. what would you like it to do? (I think you've got that covered). And 2. What does it do now? Just looking at it, I think what you're probably missing is an inner join between the city and countrylanguage tables, so you can get the right language etc values as against your city.